# Android studio's emulator not launching

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

Emulator is not launching avd. When I open avd, it shows process starting avd and completes it, but nothing happens after that. No errors and nothing. In task manager it shows running processes like adb.exe, emulator.exe. But nothing happens. It used to work fine. But this problem arose out of nowhere.
Here are the details of virtual device

Name: Pixel_2_API_29

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\admin.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_29.avd

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 29)

Skin: pixel_2

SD Card: 512 MB

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_2

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 29

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 API 29

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Pixel_2_API_29

hw.lcd.density: 420

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a7

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 2G

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Answer (score 0):

It was better if you provided some screen shots of it. Any ways it can be causing for minimum system requirement or even the power button has been pressed and its sleep. Try reinstalling it. Or you can even try using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). Its kinda lighter than android avd and even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please run following commands to clear any bug in AVDs..

```
1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server
3. adb devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop running the AVD and try wiping the data in the AVD Manager. Do a cold boot and check if the emulator runs as normal. If the problem persists, you will have to delete it and create a new virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for many months.  Only solution I found is:

```
1. Do the same steps you are using now

2. Then in AVD Manager, stop the virtual device (right click and select Stop 
   or down icon on the far right of the device line)

3. Wait for <NO DEVICE> in the top menu bar Flutter Device Selection.

4. From AVD Manager, launch the AVD again.
```

Sorry, just realized this is an old question.